# why is grpc.FutureTimeoutError not an instance of grpc.RpcError and grpc.Call?

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

It would make handling of timeouts much cleaner if FutureTimeoutError had methods like `code()` and `details()` etc, the same as, say, _InactiveRpcError does.

Is this a design decision? Would the grpc community be open to a pull request that changes the implementation of FutureTimeoutError in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grpc.FutureTimeoutError` is the exception raised when a `grpc.Future.result` or `grpc.Future.exception` exceeds deadline but haven't got any result. For example, the RPC takes 10 seconds to finish, but we got `result(timeout=2)`. Then the `grpc.FutureTimeoutError` will be raised to indicate time's up after 2 seconds. And the RPC isn't near finishing at that time, so we can't access `code()` and `details()`.

This is not a RPC issue on either the client or the server, which means `grpc.RpcError` may not be a good fit for `grpc.FutureTimeoutError`.

Comment: However, if you use a non-future `deadline` parameter, you do get an RpcError with a `e.code() == grpc.StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED`. Would it not make sense to have the same for timeouts on futures?

Comment: I agree with you. I think the API surface is trying to mimic the Python Future (https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.TimeoutError). If you feel strongly, feel free to open an issue https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues.

Comment: Thanks Lidi Zheng, I'll check out the contribution guidelines for grpc and see if I can just open a PR -- I'll let you know, maybe I can tag you as a reviewer?